# CLLocationManager compiler warning

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I implemented the following lines in order to start sending heading updates:

```
if ([locationManager headingAvailable])
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

I'm getting a compiler warning that says:

> headingAvailable is deprecated

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/headingAvailable) is pretty clear about that:

> (**Deprecated** in iOS 4.0. Use the `headingAvailable` **class method** instead.)

So `headingAvailable` is now a class method (which makes more sense actually), and not an instance method anymore. So use it as such.

```
if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable])
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
}
```